# Server on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a small script that runs a server for static `index.html` file:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs =require('fs');


var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    console.log('request was made : '+req.url);
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    var myReadStream  = fs.createReadStream(__dirname +'/index.html','utf8');
    myReadStream.pipe(res);
});

server.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1');

console.log('listening to 3000');
```

Is the a possibility  to use a string instead of 'localhost:3000' say for example 'MyPAGE' to call the html file?

Comment: Do you mean `http://localhost:3000/MyPAGE`? Or do you want to type `MyPAGE` in browser address bar?

Comment: thanks for replying I mean 'MyPage' without anything else !

Comment: It's better to use a web server for that, like `nginx` or `apache`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A URL consists of [several parts:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)

> ```
>      foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>      \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>       |           |            |            |        |
>    scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
>       |   _____________________|__
>      / \ /                        \
>      urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
> ```

In your example:

- The scheme is omitted, but the browser is implicitly adding `http://` because you are typing it into the address bar.
- The authority is made up of a hostname and a port

  - The hostname is `localhost`
  - The port is `3000`
- The path is omitted and defaults to `/`
- Everything else is omitted and has no content

In order for you to use `MyPage` you need:

- The port to be `80` (which is the default for HTTP, so you can only omit it if you use the default port)
- Your browser to resolve the hostname `MyPage` to the same IP address as `localhost` (`127.0.0.1` in this case)

So you need to:

1. Change `server.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1');` to `server.listen(80, '127.0.0.1');`. Keep in mind that port 80 is a [priviliged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) so you will need to be a root/Administrator account to run a service there.
2. Configure your DNS or `/etc/hosts` so that `MyPage` resolves to the right IP address.

Answer (score 2):

localhost is nothing but the `local server IP` i.e. `127.0.0.1` to change string **localhost** with **MyPAGE** you need to register hostname against local server IP

**For windows**
edit `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and add `127.0.0.1 MyPAGE` 
NOTE: you need to open this file as admin.

**For linux**
edit - `/etc/host` file and add `127.0.0.1 MyPAGE`